# Highcharts | Chart Zoom & Span | Zoom with LMB and Span wih RMB

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I have a Highcharts chart with the following specs.

```
chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy',
    panKey: 'shift',
    panning: true
}
```

My concern is with the 'panKey'.

How do I have pan control linked to the "mouse right button" in stead of "shift" key on keyboard?
Take this jsfiddle for reference.
http://jsfiddle.net/mqutcruw/23/
There are examples where 'click events' are registered, but I'm not sure how it can be used. (https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Utx8g/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=Utx8g)

Comment: `panKey` is used for switching between zooming and panning (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.panning). So what you're trying to achieve is zooming by clicking the left mouse button and panning by clicking the right mouse button?

Comment: That's right. And I do understand that panKey is for switching between the two. I wanted to know if we can use RMB instead of "shift" key there, or if there's any other way it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/v078hLfq/

I did some modifications in Highcharts core.

By default Highcharts completely ignores RMB event. I commented out the `if` statement responsible for that and set `rmbClicked` flag on chart instead.

```
  H.Pointer.prototype.onContainerMouseDown = function(e) {
    //if (e.button !== 2) {
    this.chart.rmbClicked = (e.button === 2); // set flag on chart - used in drag()
```

Then I used this flag in overwritten `drag` function to check whether to perform dragging or panning:

```
  if (!chart.rmbClicked) {
    // make a selection
  (...)
  } else { // right mouse button clicked
    // panning
```

Finally, I disabled the context menu event:

```
 // disable context menu on rmb click
    H.wrap(H.Pointer.prototype, 'setDOMEvents', function(proceed) {
    proceed.call(this);
    this.chart.container.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
        return false;
    }
  });
```

---

**Docs page about modifying Highcharts core:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts